# Getting the output unbuffered from subprocess is not working Python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, unbuffered

I have an exectuable that if i run it with flags it starts a tool that generate messages all the time.
When i try to run it with subprocess i get the output to the cmd and that is fine.
The thing is that i want to take this messages and do something with them but for some reason the unbuffring method is not working and I'm not getting any message .

The following is the code that I tried :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
 ["my_tool.exe","runMode","y","port","1234"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1)
```

To generate the output tried the folloing:

```
for line in p.stdout:
    print("CUR", line)
```

and:

```
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.read(2)
    print("Print:" + line)
```

and:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line)
p.stdout.close()
```

Any idea why the code blocks on the stdout line alwayes ?

**UPDATE:**

For example if i have the following infinite program:

**inf.py**

```
import time
i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

and the following code that runs it:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Python35\python.exe inf.py",
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
```

and to generate the output I'm using one of the above methods , If i stop it using CTRL+ C it is alwayes stuck on this line:

```
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 22, in decode
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
```

Comment: Perhaps this is not related, but why are you using `read(2)`?  That reads only two bytes at a time.

Comment: @JohnGordon just for testing matters.

Comment: When i cancel the operation by CTRL+C i get the following line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lg.py", line 22, in <module>
    for line in p.stdout:
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 22, in decode
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 0):

First I set the following environment variable:
`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

Then I changed your code a little:

**read_infinite.py**

```py
import subprocess

binary = "C:\\Python35\\python.exe"
script = "C:\\temp\\python\\tests\\inf.py"

p = subprocess.Popen([binary, script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

while p.poll() is None:
    #line = p.stdout.read(2)
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print("Result: %r" % line)
```

Removing `bufsize=1` works same.

The error I got at first was that the inf.py was not found, but this was not shown, because the prints of read_infinite.py scrolled the error out. And the process stopped after a lot of lines of "Result:" (variable "line" is empty).

Removing `if line:` and adding `time.sleep(0.5)` after the print (remember `import time`!) shows the same results.

So the solution is: **the parent has to wait for the child.**